# Is it possible to identify a BlackBerry users preferred time format?

Tags: blackberry

The one that is configured under options --> date/time --> Time format.

The choices are 24 or 12 hour and I would like to avoid repeating this choice in my apps if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the DATE_SHORT, DATE_MEDIUM or DATE_LONG pattern, the formatter will do what is specified in the device settings.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Not sure how I managed to miss it.